# Cleaning data with two fields mixed in the same column?

Tags: data-cleaning, excel

I am working on a template for a dashboard that is giving me some serious trouble. The format the data comes in is highly unstructured. In the image below, circled items are "Site Names", data is Month-level.

The issue is that the "Site Names" are mixed in with the Month, *with an inconsistent number of months for each site*. Some sites will display one year worth of data, others will contain up to 3 years. There is no field indicating Year, only Month.

[image]

I have managed to extract a list of unique Site Names from this column, so I have those on their own. My issue now is that I have no idea how to match them to their corresponding Months. I was thinking through how to do so with an HLOOKUP, however after planning it out briefly I'm not sure this would work. The site names I would be using as a lookup are not all present in the top row. I am absolutely stumped on how to achieve this.

Provided this isn't asking too much in one question, I also am faced with the challenge of getting Excel to understand that the first instance of a month for each site is an *older* instance of a month. I.E. "Jul" would be 2018 the first time it appears, 2019 the second time, 2020 the third time. Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest adding a company name for each corresponding month. See the attached picture.

The formula for the first column determined if it is for a month or for the company name. Assuming that all your months are in the three-letter format and there is no company named 'May' or 'Sep', the formula for the cell B2 would be

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2={"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"}))>0
```

The formula for C2 is

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$13,MATCH(2,1 /($B$2:B2=FALSE))+1)
```

Please refer to this page (https://www.get-digital-help.com/index-match-last-value/) for explanations for this formula.

Finally, you can filter the third column in my example to keep months for the specific company only. They will be in the order needed.

[image: excel spreadsheet]

Comment: I had to make a few tweaks, but this worked perfectly. Thanks very much!